# How to automatically mount CDs and DVDs on insertion?

Tags: hardware, mount

I was hoping someone could explain how to automatically mount CDs and DVDs on inserting them into the drive instead of having to open files and clicking on the drive.

I am using Freya 0.3.1.

I am also interested to see if anyone has a good solution for doing the same with USB devices (pen drives, phones, external HD).  I currently use usbmount for this and works well for pen drives but not my phone.

Jay

Comment: There should be a "Removable devices and drives" (or something like that) options in the Preferences. You can change the behavior from there.

Comment: please connect phone and add output of `sudo fdisk -l`